# How do I plot this line graph with the date on the x axis ? Error: "Plotly Express cannot process wide-form data with columns of different type."

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

My dataframe looks like this:

| title | comments | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| post1 | 256 | 2021-07-19 11:48:39 |
| post2 | 454 | 2021-07-18 22:14:41 |
| post3 | 452 | 2019-05-14 19:38:11 |
| post4 | 422 | 2018-06-14 16:38:12 |
| post5 | 452 | 2017-03-04 17:18:11 |

I would like to make a line graph with x axis showing the year and y axis showing the amount of the posts posted that year (2 in 2021, 1 in 2019 etc.)

```
titles_values = df["title"].value_counts().sum()

fig = px.line(data_frame=df, x="time" , y=titles_values)
fig.show()
```

The error I get is :
"Plotly Express cannot process wide-form data with columns of different type."

I am not sure how to go about making it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple case of summarising your data frame. `df["date"].dt.year, as_index=False).size()` calculates number of rows per year

```
import io
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""title,comments,date
post1,256,2021-07-19 11:48:39
post2,454,2021-07-18 22:14:41
post3,452,2019-05-14 19:38:11
post4,422,2018-06-14 16:38:12
post5,452,2017-03-04 17:18:11"""))
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

px.line(
    df.groupby(df["date"].dt.year, as_index=False).size(), x="date", y="size"
).update_layout(xaxis={"type": "category"}, yaxis={"dtick":1,"rangemode":"tozero"})
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do it without stringIO?

Comment: that's just the way I use to get your sample data into `df`, the solution is the `px.line(...)`